# IS this redundent data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I think I know the answer but I am not confident enough yet to just go with it.
I am thinking i have redundant info that can be fixed by just making a table for the the description . Below in my monster inserts i have 'mdesc' it has the same data that is in the dialogue inserts i just have it as 'intro'. Should i make a monster description table to hold a mdescid and and description? something like this

```
CREATE TABLE `mdesc`(
`mdescid` int(15) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`monsterdesc` varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

SO then i could just put the mdescid in both my dialogue table and the monsters table and get rid of the intro insert

```
--monster inserts
INSERT INTO monster(monsterid,monstername,monsterloc,mdesc,weaponval)values(1,dragon,11,'a dragon',1);

INSERT INTO monster(monsterid,monstername,monsterloc,mdesc,weaponval)values(2,spider,8,'a poisonus spider',2);
INSERT INTO monster(monsterid,monstername,monsterloc,mdesc,weaponval)values(3,wasps,7,'a swarm of wasps',3);
INSERT INTO monster(monsterid,monstername,monsterloc,mdesc,weaponval)values(4,enchantress,13,'a seductive enchantress',4);
INSERT INTO monster(monsterid,monstername,monsterloc,mdesc,weaponval)values(5,bellyfish,5,'a slimy belly fish',5);

-- dialogue inserts
INSERT INTO dialogue(monsterid,intro,attack,outcome1,outcome2,outcome3)
    values(1,'"a dragon."','"you fight and,"','" kill it with your sword!"','"it kills and eats you."','" you both run away!"');
```

Comment: What is the purpose of a third table? Can you use use `monster.mdesc` for the dialogue? What is the purpose of a separate `dialogue` table? Could this all be in a single `monster` table?

Comment: Will the value of `outcome1, outcome2, outcome3` be the same for any monster?

Comment: @Schwern   I didn't finish all the inserts yet for dialogue, each monster will have different dialogue for each outcome. I just thought that would be to much for one table ?

Comment: @FanoFN    I didn't finish all the inserts yet for dialogue, each monster will have different dialogue for each outcome.

Comment: @JmL There's no reason to spread the info for one monster over three tables. That's called a [one-to-one relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_(data_model)), one row of a table relates to only row of another table, and vice versa. It's rarely useful. What you could do is change `dialogue` to have the monster, situation, and text. `(1, 'description', 'a dragon'), (1, 'attack', 'you fight and')`. This avoids having to add a column every time you come up with a new situation. That is one-to-many: one monster has many dialogues. If a monster has no dialogue use a default.

Comment: @Schwern Thank you for clarifying, after some more googling and tinkering around I ended up with  pretty much what you said.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to spread the info for one monster over three tables. That's called a [one-to-one relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_(data_model)), one row of a table relates to only row of another table, and vice versa. It's rarely useful.

What you could do is change dialogue to have the monster, situation, and text.

```
create table monster_dialogues (
  monster_id integer not null
    foreign key(monster_id) references monsters(id)
  situation varchar(255) not null,
  dialogue varchar(255) not null

  unique(monster_id, situation)
)
```

This is a [one-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)), each monster has many dialogues. This avoids having to add a new column every time you have a new situation.

And instead of reproducing the same basic text over and over, have a default in your code.

```
-- Note, avoid including formatting like quotes and conjunctions in your data.
-- It restricts how the data can be used.
-- Leave the formatting of dialogue into sentences to the application.
select coalesce(dialogue, 'you fight')
from monster_dialogues
where monster_id = ?
  and situation = 'attack'
```

Note that using a database for this is probably overkill. Unless there's a very large number of monsters or you need to search through a large number of dialogues a simple JSON file would do.

```
{
  "dragon": {
    "damage": 100,
    "health": 200,
    "dialogues": {
      "attack": "you fight",
    }
  }
}
```